Manually set IIS Express Edge (from VS) into compatibility mode?
I searched thru all the similar questions here in stackoverflow but there was no mention on how to manually set compatibility mode for the IIS Express - Edge (from VS).  I'm not talking setting in web.config or via aspx page, but manually from the browser.
On a deployed app (to IIS 10 web server), I can test via MS Edge manually setting and unsetting compatibility mode but no such option seems to be available when working localhost IIS Express - Edge from VS.

Then it has little to do with IIS Express and removed that tag.

Do you mean you want to set open Edge IE mode in VS settings? Or do you want to know if there's "from VS" setting in Edge browser?

As stated, when running my ASP.NET app from VS with the option to use "IIS Express (Microsoft Edge)" there is no browser setting that can be manually set to enable/disable compatibility mode ... key being "manually" not via code.  Because of corporate managed group policy the weg.config and page settings for compatibility mode are overriden (ignored) ... these:  and  do not work because of group policy.

@LexLi not helpful.  Again, this is only via the IIS Express (Microsoft Edge) launch option from VS 2022.  On deployed test and development IIS 10.x web servers I can use the "normal" version of Edge and set compatibility mode manually (upper right icon) and define URLs to be loaded in compatibility mode (30 day max).  This is ONLY with MS Edge, other browsers don't support this.  So yes, it's all about IIS Express.

Why is it that when I come here with a question or ask for helpful, it ends up being a moderator battle?  This is good how?  Remove a tag with zero explanation ... what does this do for those viewing?  This is the reason why stackoverflow has such a bad reputation amount the developer community.

You explicitly ruled out any server side changes related by saying "I'm not talking setting in web.config or via aspx page, but manually from the browser" and I honored your determination and changed the tags to engage the right audience. I am not sure what's wrong with that and caused you so much pain. The option name "IIS Express (Edge)" is rather misleading itself, but again that's only related to Visual Studio and Edge.

@LexLi That's what VS 2022 identifies it as "IIS Express (Microsoft Edge)" so one assumes it's using IIS Express.  This is not "Kestrel", nor is it "IIS", it's a special version integrated into VS designed for developers.  When operating from VS thru IIS Express the browser does not present the same compatibility mode options as that provided by "Edge" ... the compatibility mode button just doesn't exist vs. a normal session with "Edge" ... this is most definitely an IIS Express issue and the browser is not the same as standard "Edge".  Yes, these are legacy projects.

@RobAinscough Excuse me, what is the compatibility mode you mentioned, do you mean 'Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode (IE mode)' in Edge settings? If yes, does the edge profile accounts be the same?

This issue was resolved by changing the "Script Debugging" to Disable. Once that is performed the compatibility option will appear in IIS Express Edge.

